# Problema con la asignación del tamaño a un array

Tags: c, array

Estoy trabajando en un programa que te dice si una palabra o frase es palíndromo o no. Para hacer eso leo un array de caracteres y remuevo los espacios contándolos con un ciclo y creando un segundo array cuyo tamaño es la cantidad de caracteres del array anterior menos los espacios. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero por alguna razón el segundo array se crea con un tamaño mayor al especificado dejando caracteres vacíos y como consecuencia el programa siempre marca que la frase no es un palíndromo.

Esta es la parte de mi código que se encarga de hacer lo que mencioné. Agregué la impresión de las variables para comprobar que todo esté bien.

```
void main() {
int x, i, y = 0, tamano, espacios = 0;
char cadena[100];
printf("Por favor introduzca su cadena.\n");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &cadena);
//gets(cadena);
printf("tamano de cadena %i\n", strlen(cadena));
for (x = 0; x < strlen(cadena); x++) {
    if (cadena[x] == 32) {
        espacios++;
    }
}
printf("espacios %i\n", espacios);
tamano = strlen(cadena) - espacios;
printf("tamano sin espacios %i\n", tamano);
char cadena_aux[tamano], cadena_invertida[tamano];
printf("tamano de cadena auxiliar %i\n", sizeof(cadena_aux));
for (x = 0; y < tamano; x++) {
    if (cadena[x] != 32) {
        cadena_aux[y] = cadena[x];
        y++;
    }
}
```

Si introduzco `"hola hola"` el resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de lecturas es preferible usar `getline`:

```
char* cadena = NULL;
getline(&cadena, 100, stdin);

// ...

free(cadena);
```

Ahora bien, esta función tiene dos pegas principales:

1. Solo está disponible en sistemas POSIX (linux)
2. la cadena contendrá el salto de línea (que podrá estar compuesto de uno o dos caracteres)

Así que puedes crear facilmente tu propia versión. La gracia está en leer caracteres hasta que nos topamos con el salto de línea:

```
size_t get_line(char** buffer, size_t* length)
{
  size_t string_length = 0;
  while(1)
  {
    char c = fgetc(stdin);
    if( c == '\n' || c == '\r' )
      break;

    if( *length == string_length )
    {
      *length += 10;
      *buffer = (char*)realloc(*buffer,*length*sizeof(char));
    }

    (*buffer)[string_length] = c;
    string_length++;    
  }

  return string_length;
}
```

Con lo que para leer una cadena en tu programa ahora simplemente tendrías que hacer esto:

```
char *cadena = NULL;
size_t cadena_sizeof = 0;
printf("Por favor introduzca su cadena.\n");
size_t cadena_length = get_line(&cadena, &cadena_sizeof);
```

Además, nota que estás haciendo uso de **VLA** (Variable Length Array), es decir, arrays cuya longitud se determina en tiempo de ejecución, y los mismos no están soportados por el estándar desde C99 (que data de 1999)... si te funciona es porque tu compilador (o alguna extensión del mismo) te hace el favor... pero esa solución puede dejar de funcionarte en cualquier momento.

```
char cadena_aux[tamano], cadena_invertida[tamano];  // <<--- VLAs
```

La solución pasa por usar `malloc` y `free`:

```
char* cadena_aux = (char*)malloc(tamano*sizeof(char));

// ...

free(cadena_aux);
```